# Returned values are not the same as written out

Tags: c++, c++11, return

So I've been writing a program and it's almost done but I met with a trouble. I am a beginner in programming so the code is not written perfectly, I don't even know classes. The program has many Polish things but I tried to translate some so there should not be any problem with understanding.
And yes, I used using `namespace std;` here, I know it is a bad practise, sorry.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char startLUBwyjscie; //startORexit
char yesorno;
int mojeHP = 100, HPosmiornicy = 100, mojaEN = 100; //myHP, Octopu'sHP, myENERGY
int wyborAtaku; //choosingTheAttack
char clickO;
//char spamX; not useful now
char clickanything;
char clickanything2;
char clickanything3; //idk if 3 variables are necessary but made it in case of problems
ofstream zapisfout; //for saving smth to the file
ifstream odczytfin; //for reading-out smth from the file
string wartoscdoodczytu; //AValueToRead-out
int liniapliku = 0; //LineOfFile
char choosethelanguage;

int PowerfulPunch(); //prototypes
int KnifeThrow();
int NormalAttack();
int OctopusAttack();
int WhosNext();


unsigned ziarno_liczb_losowych = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count(); //seed
default_random_engine silnik_liczb_losowych(ziarno_liczb_losowych); //engine



int main()
{
    cout << "Wybierz jezyk / Choose the language" << endl;
    cout << "1. Polski (bez polskich znakow) / Polish (without Polish characters)" << endl; //does not exist, a limit of characters in my post has been exceeded so I had to delete this option
    cout << "2. English / Angielski" << endl; //click 2 always
    choosethelanguage = _getch(); //choose the language

    if (choosethelanguage == '2') //English version
    {
        system("cls");


    menu: //label
        srand(time(NULL));
        cout << "DEPTH OF ABYSSAL SEA" << endl << endl;

        cout << "1. Start" << endl;
        cout << "2. Instructions" << endl;
        cout << "3. Read-out logs of the last fight" << endl;
        cout << "4. Credits" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
        startLUBwyjscie = _getch(); //menu
        switch (startLUBwyjscie)
        {
        case '1': //a story and the game
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Do you want to pass over the exordium? Click 'X' to pass over the exordium. Click anything else to read the exordium." << endl;
            yesorno = _getch();
            if (yesorno == 'X' || yesorno == 'x') //pass over the exordium (y/n)
                goto koniecwstepu; //go to the label
            else //exordium (story)
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << "The strory begins so many years ago." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You are Felix. You are nineteen years old." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You were born on Malta - country situated on the Mediterraen Sea. Simply a little island." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Your grandfather told you a story which was about the Atlantis." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "It seemed like a fairy tale, something, what doesn't even exist." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "It was told that the Atlantis was situated on the Arctic Ocean. It seemed to be a long way from here." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "But the story was told many years ago, when you were eight. Your grandfather died several years ago." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "It is touching, isn't it?" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "But even when you were growing up, you didn't stop believing in the story." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You are too young to see some things. You look from the shallow perspective." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You demand an adventure! You think that you are the chosen one. The chosen one to know the secret." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You took every things that might be useful in case of meeting ruins of destroyed continent." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "But will you able to rise to the challenge?" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Let's see..." << endl;
                Sleep(10000);
            koniecwstepu: //label
                system("cls");
            }

            zapisfout.open("Logs of the last fight.txt", ios::trunc); //deleting the content before next informations
            zapisfout.close(); //closing file


        //the game
            for (int i = 1; ((mojeHP <= 100 && mojeHP > 0) && (HPosmiornicy <= 100 && HPosmiornicy > 0)); i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    cout << "Your HP: " << mojeHP << endl;
                    cout << "Your Energy: " << mojaEN << endl << endl;
                    cout << "Octopus' HP: " << HPosmiornicy << endl << endl << endl;
                }

            blad: //label blad (błąd means error in this case but I cannot use polish characters so I named the label 'blad')

                cout << "Round " << i << endl;

                if (WhosNext() == 1)
                    cout << "Your turn" << endl << endl;
                else
                    cout << "Octopus' turn" << endl << endl;

                cout << "Available actions: " << endl;
                cout << "1. Powerful punch (-30 Energy)" << endl;
                cout << "2. Knife throw (-45 Energy)" << endl;
                cout << "3. Normal attack (+30 Energy)" << endl;
                wyborAtaku = _getch();
                cout << endl << endl;

                if (wyborAtaku == '1') // Powerful Punch
                {
                    if (mojaEN - 30 <= 0)
                    {
                        cout << "You don't have enough energy!" << endl << endl << endl; //brak energii
                        goto blad; //go to the label
                    }


                    cout << "You deal " << PowerfulPunch() << " damage to the octopus." << endl;
                    cout << "The octopus deals you " << OctopusAttack() << " damage." << endl << endl << endl;
                    mojeHP -= OctopusAttack();      //substract my HP
                    mojaEN -= 30;                           //substract the energy
                    HPosmiornicy -= PowerfulPunch();    //substract octpus' HP

                    if (mojeHP <= 0)
                        cout << "Your HP: 0" << endl; //showing my HP <0
                    else
                        cout << "Your HP: " << mojeHP << endl; //showing my HP >0

                    cout << "Your Energy: " << mojaEN << endl << endl; //showing my energy

                    if (mojeHP <= 0)
                        cout << "Octopu's HP: 0" << endl; //showing octopus' HP <0
                    else
                        cout << "Octopus' HP: " << HPosmiornicy << endl << endl << endl; //showing octopus' HP >0   
                }

                else if (wyborAtaku == '2') // Knife throw
                {
                    if (mojaEN - 45 <= 0)
                    {
                        cout << "You don't have enough energy!" << endl << endl << endl;
                        goto blad;
                    }

                    cout << "You deal " << KnifeThrow() << " damage to the octopus." << endl;
                    cout << "The octopus deals you " << OctopusAttack() << " damage." << endl << endl << endl;
                    mojeHP -= OctopusAttack();      //substract my HP
                    mojaEN -= 45;                       //substract the energy
                    HPosmiornicy -= KnifeThrow();   //substract octpus' HP

                    if (mojeHP <= 0)
                        cout << "Your HP: 0" << endl; //showing my HP <0
                    else
                        cout << "Your HP: " << mojeHP << endl; //showing my HP >0

                    cout << "Your Energy: " << mojaEN << endl << endl; //showing my energy

                    if (mojeHP <= 0)
                        cout << "Octopu's HP: 0" << endl; //showing octopus' HP <0
                    else
                        cout << "Octopus' HP: " << HPosmiornicy << endl << endl << endl; //showing octopus' HP >0

                }

                else if (wyborAtaku == '3') // Normal attack
                {
                    cout << "You deal " << NormalAttack() << " damage to the octopus." << endl;
                    cout << "The octopus deals you " << OctopusAttack() << " damage." << endl << endl << endl;
                    mojeHP -= OctopusAttack();      //substract my HP
                    mojaEN += 30;                           //adding the energy
                    HPosmiornicy -= NormalAttack(); //substract octpus' HP

                    if (mojeHP <= 0)
                        cout << "Your HP: 0" << endl; //showing my HP <0
                    else
                        cout << "Your HP: " << mojeHP << endl; //showing my HP >0

                    cout << "Your Energy: " << mojaEN << endl << endl;  //showing my energy

                    if (HPosmiornicy <= 0)
                        cout << "Octopus' HP: 0" << endl; //showing octopus' HP <0
                    else
                        cout << "Octopus' HP: " << HPosmiornicy << endl << endl << endl; //showing octopus' HP >0

                }

                else if ((wyborAtaku != '1' && wyborAtaku != '2' && wyborAtaku != '3') || !isdigit(wyborAtaku))
                {
                    cout << "Incorrect character!" << endl << endl << endl;
                    goto blad;
                }

                zapisfout.open("Logs of the last fight.txt", ios::app); //opening the file and actualizing date in it
                zapisfout << "Round " << i << endl;

                if (mojeHP <= 0)
                    zapisfout << "Your HP: 0" << endl; //showing my HP <0 in file
                else
                    zapisfout << "Your HP: " << mojeHP << endl; //showing my HP >0 in file

                zapisfout << "Your Energy: " << mojaEN << endl; //showing my energy in file

                if (HPosmiornicy <= 0)
                    zapisfout << "Octopus' HP: 0" << endl; //showing octopus' HP <0 in file
                else
                    zapisfout << "Octopus' HP: " << HPosmiornicy << endl << endl << endl; //showing octopus' HP >0 in file

                zapisfout.close(); //closing the file

            }

            if ((HPosmiornicy <= 0 && WhosNext() == 1 && mojeHP <= 0) || (HPosmiornicy <= 0 && (WhosNext() == 2 || WhosNext() == 1) && mojeHP > 0))
            {
                cout << endl << endl;
                cout << "VICTORY!!!" << endl << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "What?! It's impossible!" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Some feeble human could slay that enermous creature?" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "I can't believe..." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You had actually nothing brought from your home..." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Some food and drink, diving disguise and some blunt knives..." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "This world is impressive and never will stop surprising me." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You see how the octopus is sinking in the sand. You can take your treasure!" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You deserve, to be honest." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Hey, let's make it! Open it!" << endl << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "*CLICK 'O' TO OPEN*" << endl;
            open: //label 'open'
                clickO = _getch();
                if (clickO == 'o' || clickO == 'O')
                {
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "You made it! Wow... These are truly beatiful..." << endl;
                    Sleep(2500);
                    cout << "You are so wealthy right now..." << endl;
                    Sleep(2500);
                    cout << "Golden ingots, diamond trident and some gems..." << endl;
                    Sleep(2500);
                    cout << "Wow... I haven't seen the things like that since billions years..." << endl; //Look at your oxygen in your bottle! You are getting strangled! SWIM UP, SWIM UP!!!"<<endl<<endl; //not really important here now 
                    Sleep(2500);
                    //cout<<"*SPAM 'X' TO SWIM UP (25 to get out in 10 seconds)* "<<endl; //not really important here now 
                    cout << "It's time for you now. Congratulations." << endl << endl;
                    Sleep(2500);
                    cout << "GOOD ENDING" << endl << endl;

                    zapisfout.open("Logs of the last fight.txt", ios::app);
                    zapisfout << "GOOD ENDING" << endl; //actualizing data in the file with an ending
                    zapisfout.close(); //closing the file

                    Sleep(10000);

                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "*WRONG CHARACTER!*" << endl << endl;
                    goto open; //coming back to 'open' label
                }
            }

            else if ((HPosmiornicy <= 0 && WhosNext() == 2 && mojeHP <= 0) || (HPosmiornicy > 0 && (WhosNext() == 2 || WhosNext() == 1) && mojeHP <= 0))
            {
                cout << endl << endl;
                cout << "DEFEAT!!!" << endl << endl;

                cout << "Happened. You died. You are a ghost." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Impossible?" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "For sure you are wondering how it happened..." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "For sure you are wondering where you are now..." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "HELLO?!" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "No one hears you. It is the world of the all dead beings such as people but also animals." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Don't worry. You can't die here. It wouldn't be logical. But you can be vexed by other creatures living here." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Now you can worry." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "What happened to the octopus, you probably wonder." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "It is still alive and it is waiting for other daredevils that will think that they are, as you named it, 'the chosen ones'. Funny cycle, isn't it?" << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Sorry, you didn't manage to slay the creature." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "You were too weak." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "Oh look! Something approaches to you! Looks known..." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "-I said that the Atlantis had existed..." << endl << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                cout << "BAD ENDING" << endl << endl;

                zapisfout.open("Logs of the last fight.txt", ios::app);
                zapisfout << "BAD ENDING" << endl; //actualizing data in the file with an ending
                zapisfout.close(); //closing the file

                Sleep(10000);
            }


            break;
        }
        case '2': //just explaining the game
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "You start the game in menu. There you can choose an option:" << endl;
            cout << "1. Start, if you want to start the game." << endl;
            cout << "2. Instructions, if you want to know how to play the game, the place where you are now." << endl;
            cout << "3. Read-out logs of the last fight to see the course of the latest battle." << endl;
            cout << "4. Exit, if you want to go out of the game." << endl << endl;
            cout << "After clicking Start you are going to see the exordium which you can pass over by clicking 'x'." << endl;
            cout << "The exordium brings you into the main story." << endl;
            cout << "In game, you have three bars:" << endl;
            cout << "Your HP" << endl;
            cout << "Your Energy" << endl;
            cout << "Octopus' HP" << endl;
            cout << "The bars show the level of your health points, your energy points and octopus' health points." << endl;
            cout << "Your HP goes down when octopus attacks you." << endl;
            cout << "Your energy is spent by using your abilities." << endl;
            cout << "Octopus' HP goes down when you attack it." << endl;
            cout << "All abilities always deal damage, there cannot be a situation when the skills deal 0 damage." << endl;
            cout << "All values on the start are equal 100." << endl;
            cout << "Every dealt damage is generated by random numbers or psuedorandom numbers. It all depends of RNG god." << endl;
            cout << "Your character has 3 spells: " << endl;
            cout << "1. Powerful Punch" << endl;
            cout << "This spell uses 30 of your energy and deals 20-35 damage." << endl;
            cout << "2. Knife Throw" << endl;
            cout << "This spell uses 45 of your energy and deals 36-50 damage." << endl;
            cout << "3. Normal Attack" << endl;
            cout << "This spell gives you 30 energy and deals 1-15 damage." << endl;
            cout << "The octopus doesn't have any special attacks but it always deals damage 1-50 damage." << endl;
            cout << "As it was told, octopus doesn't have any special attacks, so it doesn't have energy points too." << endl;
            cout << "The battle is split on rounds." << endl;
            cout << "Every round is began by the octopus or by you, all depends of drawn order." << endl;
            cout << "If Your HP and Octopus' HP are equal 0, then drawn order decides about victory and defeat." << endl << endl;
            cout << "CLICK ANYTHING TO EXIT THE ISTRUCTIONS AND REGAIN TO THE MAIN MENU" << endl;

            clickanything = _getch();

            if (clickanything)
            {
                cout << "You will be brought to the main menu in a moment." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                system("cls");
                goto menu; //going to the 'menu' label          
            }

            break;

        }
        case '3': //file
        {
            system("cls");
            odczytfin.open("Logs of the last fight.txt"); //opening the file

            if (!odczytfin.is_open())
            {
                cout << "It was not able to open the file! You will be brought to the main menu in a moment." << endl;
                Sleep(2500);
                system("cls");
                goto menu; //going to the 'menu' label
            }


            while (odczytfin.good()) //checking if the file is okay
            {
                liniapliku++;
                getline(odczytfin, wartoscdoodczytu);
                cout << wartoscdoodczytu << endl;
            }


            if (odczytfin.eof()) //if eof(), click anything
            {
                cout << endl << endl;
                cout << "CLICK ANYTHING TO EXIT THE LOGS AND REGAIN TO THE MAIN MENU" << endl;

                clickanything2 = _getch();

                if (clickanything2)
                {
                    cout << "You will be brought to the main menu in a moment." << endl;
                    Sleep(2500);
                    system("cls");
                    goto menu; //going to the 'menu' label          
                }

            }
            odczytfin.close(); //closing the file
        }

        case '4': //credits
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "The game was whole made by Vatnax. (and the guys who helped me with a problem)" << endl << endl;
            cout << "CLICK ANYTHING TO EXIT THE CREDITS AND REGAIN TO THE MAIN MENU" << endl;

            clickanything3 = _getch();
            if (clickanything3)
            {
                Sleep(2500);
                system("cls");
                goto menu; //going to the 'menu' label
                break;
            }
        }
        case '5': //exit
        {
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        default: //if input wrong value in a menu
        {
            cout << "Incorrect value! You will be brought to the main menu in a moment." << endl;
            Sleep(2500);
            system("cls");
            goto menu; //going to the 'menu' label
            break;
        }

        }

    }
}
//functions
int PowerfulPunch()
{
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(20, 35); //distributor of a random number
    return dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(silnik_liczb_losowych); //returning this number with the engine and the seed which are declared on the beginning of the code
}

int KnifeThrow()
{
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(36, 50); //distributor of a random number
    return dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(silnik_liczb_losowych); //returning this number with the engine and the seed which are declared on the beginning of the code
}

int NormalAttack()
{
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(1, 15); //distributor of a random number
    return dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(silnik_liczb_losowych); //returning this number with the engine and the seed which are declared on the beginning of the code
}

int OctopusAttack()
{
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(1, 50); //distributor of a random number
    return dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(silnik_liczb_losowych); //returning this number with the engine and the seed which are declared on the beginning of the code
}

int WhosNext() //responsible for who starts the round
{
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(1, 2); //distributor of a random number
    return dystrybutor_liczb_losowych(silnik_liczb_losowych); //returning this number with the engine and the seed which are declared on the beginning of the code
}
```

It's the long code, but half of this is a Polish version of the program.
The problem is that the values returned from functions are subtracted later from current `mojeHP` variable state. After it, `mojeHP` is shown but it doesn't have the value as it should have. It is all made in the lines 146-162, 173-189, 195-211.

I copied the whole code because I don't even know where the problem is so maybe all the code will be needed, not only a piece of it.

E.g.:

Your HP: 100

Your Energy: 100

Octopus' HP: 100

Round 1

Your turn

Available actions:

1. Powerful punch (-30 Energy)
2. Knife throw (-45 Energy)
3. Normal attack (+30 Energy)

You deal 15 damage to the octopus.
The octopus deals you 12 damage.

Your HP: 66 // 100 - 12 is not equal 66

Your Energy: 130 // this one is written out as it should have been because there is always added 30 energy in this case

Octopus' HP: 91 // 100 - 15 is not equal 91

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve]. Please don't dump a whole bunch of unnecessary code and expect people to go through them to find the needle in a hay stack.

Comment: This is a problem that could easily be solved by debugging. Generally it's expected of the asker to have attempted debugging before opening a question - have you tried this yet? If so, what were your findings? If not, or you don't know how to debug, simply ask. Once you debug, you can find the section of code causing issue, and if you still can't figure it out, *only then* should you post a question, along with the *relevant* snippet of troublesome code.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code seems to be:

```
cout << "You deal " << NormalAttack() << " damage to the octopus." << endl;
cout << "The octopus deals you " << OctopusAttack() << " damage." << endl << endl << endl;
mojeHP -= OctopusAttack();      //substract my HP
mojaEN += 30;                           //adding the energy
HPosmiornicy -= NormalAttack(); //substract octpus' HP
```

Each time you call `NormalAttack()` a new random number is generated. As you are calling it twice you get 2 numbers, print one and use the other to update the hit points. Your code should be:

```
auto myAttack = NormalAttack();
auto enemyAttack = OctopusAttack();
cout << "You deal " << myAttack << " damage to the octopus." << endl;
cout << "The octopus deals you " << enemyAttack  << " damage." << endl << endl << endl;
mojeHP -= enemyAttack;      //substract my HP
mojaEN += 30;                           //adding the energy
HPosmiornicy -= myAttack; //substract octpus' HP
```

There is no need to have a copies of your code for each language, just put all your language strings in an array or map and choose which array to use to change the language (or for a real project use an internationalisation framework). e.g. something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> english =
{ 
  { "hello", "Hello" },
  { "goodbye", "Goodbye" },
};

std::map<std::string, std::string> polish =
{ 
  { "hello", "Witaj" },
  { "goodbye", "Do widzenia" },
};

auto& language = choosethelanguage == '2' ? english : polish;

std::cout << language["hello"] << "\n";
std::cout << language["goodbye"] << "\n";
```

You'd probably want to wrap the string lookup into a function to check for invalid values and return back the key instead of the empty string that would result from the above code.

Comment: It works, now I see what was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Vatnax feel free to up upvote and/or accept this answer if it solved your problem